# Is there any performance gain from renaming a minified file to have the *.min.js extension?

Tags: javascript

I have a minified angular-ui-bootstrap file that I'm including inside my angular application. Right now it's named `foo.js` even though the contents of the file itself is minified javascript. If I rename the file to `foo.min.js`, does that make any difference? Does the server see the `min.js` extension and somehow serve the file faster or is renaming the file simply a matter of semantics so other programmers know it's a minified file without opening it?

Comment: Normally just indicates that the file has been minified. No performance gains in the naming of the file itself.

Comment: You're changing the file name and nothing more

Comment: You actually add 4 bytes!! (kidding)

Comment: Since you're wondering about serving files faster- I want to mention that servers typically compress static files. This is usually out of the box behavior. `foo.js` is minified and chances are your server is compressing the minified file as well, minimizing the payload as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for semantics.  It can make troubleshooting or build process analysis easier.  It also helps with build tools like Grunt or Gulp which read in a file and output a file.

There is no performance benefit based on the file name.  The performance benefit comes from the fact that the minified file is smaller.  That's all.